# Llenar un Array multidimensional con datos desde un formulario HTML JS

Tags: html5, array, javascript-objeto

estoy desarrollando un programa que obtiene datos desde un formulario HTML, tengo la función que obtiene los datos pero requiero de un Array que almacene esos datos temporalmente cada que se envían los datos y poderlos obtener en consola con el siguiente formato ej: [[nombre, direccion, correo][nombre, direccion, correo]], lo he intentado pero solo he podido guardar el primer array y cada que ingreso datos se sobreescriben.(solo es de manera temporal, se que cuando reinicie el navegador se borrarán).

```
<form name="formulario" id="form-registro" onsubmit="return checkNombre(), checkTelefono(), checkDir(), checkCorreo()">
    <label for="" id="Nombre">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="nombre"><br>
        <div>
            <legend>Género</legend>
            <label for="" id="Genero"><input type="radio" name="Genero" value="M" id="M">M</label>
            <label for="" id="Genero"><input type="radio" name="Genero" value="F" id="F">F</label>
        </div>
    <br>
    <label for="" id="Telefono">Teléfono</label>
    <input type="tel" name="" id="telefono"><br>
    <label for="" id="Direccion">Dirección</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="direccion"><br>
    <label for="" id="Correo">Correo</label>
    <input type="email" name="" id="correo" autocomplete="username"><br>
    <label for="" id="Pass">Contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" name="" id="pass" autocomplete="current-password"><br>
    <div id="div-btn-registrar2"></div>
        <input type="submit" id="btn-submit-form" value="Registrar" onclick="return agregarRegistro()">
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
function agregarRegistro(){ 
this.Nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
this.Genero = document.formulario.Genero.value;
this.Telefono = document.getElementById("telefono").value;
this.Direccion = document.getElementById("direccion").value;
this.Correo = document.getElementById("correo").value;
this.Pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;

console.log("Nombre: "+Nombre+" Genero: "+Genero+" Telefono: "+Telefono+" Direccion: "+Direccion+" Correo: "+Correo+" Password: "+Pass);
}
```